# java web service export jar eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jar, import

I have created web service client using wsdl in eclipse. Now I would like to export that client to some library as .jar and use it in other projects by import [that service] and create `service name_service  = new service....`    How do I do that? Is there tutorial for that? Could not find it on google

Comment: There is another way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create it from the command prompt. e.g. from the WSDL document file of http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx:

```
C:\Users\Paul>cd \tmp

C:\tmp>md wsclient

C:\tmp>cd wsclient

C:\tmp\wsclient>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\wsimport http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL
parsing WSDL...

generating code...

compiling code...

C:\tmp\wsclient>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jar cf wsclient.jar *


C:\tmp\wsclient>tree /a /f
C:.
|   wsclient.jar
|
\---net
    \---webservicex
            ConversionRate.class
            ConversionRateResponse.class
            Currency.class
            CurrencyConvertor.class
            CurrencyConvertorSoap.class
            ObjectFactory.class
            package-info.class
```

The web service client generated is the file `wsclient.jar`, which you can use in other projects. The `wsimport` tool is included in the Java JDK since the version 6.

Optionally you can perform one additional task. Look at it in [*Use a WSDL document file locally*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18923391/870248).